# Blazor Web Assembly - Event Not Working Correctly

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have a Blazor WebAssembly (.NET 6) application. I am using the [MudBlazor](https://mudblazor.com/) component library.

I have a `MudTextField` (*text area*) and `MudFab` (*button*) like this:

```razor
 <MudTextField T="string" Label="Message" Variant="Variant.Outlined" @bind-Value="@newMessage" Clearable="true" Lines="2" />
 <MudFab Color="Color.Primary" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Send" OnClick="@SendAsync" />
```

In the `OnClick` event handler of the `MudFab` (button), I am calling `SendAsync` function, which looks like the following:

```razor
async Task SendAsync()
{
    //some logic
    await _client.SendMessageAsync(newMessage);      
}
```

So user types text in `MudTextField`. Then hits send button (MudFab), and `SendAsync` method mentioned above gets executed. Everything so far works fine.

Now I want to add feature where user can press <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd> key while typing message, and this should execute `SendAsync` function. i.e, user does not have to use mouse and click send button (MudFab).

For this, I added following event handler in my code, and bound it to `OnKeyDown` event. The code looks like this:

```razor
// notice 'OnKeyDown'
<MudTextField T="string" Label="Message" Variant="Variant.Outlined" @bind-Value="@newMessage" Clearable="true" Lines="2" OnKeyDown="HandleKeyDown"/>
<MudFab Color="Color.Primary" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Send" OnClick="@SendAsync" />

....

private async Task HandleKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CtrlKey && e.Key == "Enter")
    {
        await SendAsync();
    }
}
```

**Problem**

This code only works if I place a breakpoint in the `HandleKeyDown` method. Otherwise it doesn't work at all. I have been struggling for more than two days to make this simple logic work. What am I missing?

Things I have tried:

- Tried adding `StateChanged()` after `SendAsync()`, but did not work.
- Tried changing `MudTextField` to simple `<input>`, and `MudFab` to simple `button`, but did not work.
- Tried to use Javascript Interop, it also did not work.

Last I tried doing it using jQuery as shown here, but it also had the same problem. It only worked if I place 'debugger;' in the `on("keydown"...` function:

```js
// this code is inside <script> tag:
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handle key press event
    $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === "Enter") {
            
            e.preventDefault(); /
            //debugger; ------->> WORKS fine if I uncomment this
            $("#btnChat_SendMessage").click();
            console.log("pressed::ctrl-Enter::::::::::::::");

            // tried Adding a slight delay
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#btnChat_SendMessage").trigger("click");
            }, 2000); 
        }
    });
});
```

If I check browser console, I can see

```js
pressed::ctrl-Enter::::::::::::::
```

printed on the console. It is printed as many times as I have hit <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>. But logic doesn't get executed.

If I run `$("#btnChat_SendMessage").trigger("click");` directly on the browser console, the logic gets executed just fine.

Why is this happening? Can somebody please point out my mistake.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `KeyDownPreventDefault` property on `MudTextField` to specify which keys need to be overriden. [MudText docs](https://mudblazor.com/api/textfield#properties:%7E:text=KeyDownPreventDefault)

In the example below, a boolean field `_preventDefault` is created to keep track of which keys to override. Then we call the `SendAsync()` function only when the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> 's are pressed.

```razor
<MudTextField T="string" @bind-Value="@_newMessage"
            OnKeyDown="HandleOnKeyDown"
            KeyDownPreventDefault="@_preventDefault"
            Immediate="true"
            Variant="Variant.Outlined" Clearable="true" Lines="2" Label="Message"/>
 <MudFab Color="Color.Primary" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Send" OnClick="@SendAsync" />

<h2>@_sendAsyncMessage</h2>
@code {
    string _newMessage="";
    bool _preventDefault = false;
    string _sendAsyncMessage="";
    public async Task HandleOnKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == "Enter" && e.CtrlKey)
        {
            _preventDefault=true;
            await SendAsync();
        }
        else{
            _preventDefault=false;
        }
    }
    async Task SendAsync()
    {
        _sendAsyncMessage = $"Sent message:{_newMessage}";
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        _sendAsyncMessage="";
    }
}
```

[MudBlazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mumxaDlGgHgKTvRq)

**Note** I added `Immediate="true"` property because the example relies on the `_newMessage` being bound on each key press. Use/remove it according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked. Just FYI, it doesn't work if I remove `Immediate="true"`. I'm not sure if it is safe to keep true in my case : | My use case is: user types message, and on Ctrl+Enter, it is sent to through SignalR hub client. The docs say `"...If false, the Value is updated only on Enter"`. So shouldn't it work even if I keep it "false"?

Comment: It's basically the difference between using `@oninput` and `@onchange`, for your usecase it should be true